# Initial call to setItemChecked in Fragment list not working

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am attempting to select an item within a list Fragment `onCreateView`. I do this as follows: `listView.setItemChecked(position, true);`.  Unfortunately the view is not activated, as in my `ArrayAdapter` `getView` is never called so I am unable to modify the checked item.  Any suggestions or links are appreciated!

**Fragment onCreateView**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout=  inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    mListView= (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);


    mListView.setAdapter(new Adapter(
            this,
            R.layout.list_item,
            titles));
    mListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

    return layout;
}
```

**ArrayAdapter**

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Activity mActivity;
private int mResource;

public Adapter(Fragment fragment, int resource, ArrayList<String> titles) {
    super(fragment.getActivity(), resource, titles);
    mActivity = fragment.getActivity();
    mResource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(getItem(position));
    holder.title.setTypeface(null, convertView.isActivated() ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    private TextView title;
}
}
```

**EDIT**
The following code works fine for some reason in detecting an activation, why is it that my custom adapter won't work?

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    "ONE",
                    "TWO"
            }));
```

Comment: what do you mean by `Unfortunately the view is not activated,` can you post an image what it looks like

Comment: Normal is unactivated, bold is activated (see array adapter typeface change).  The view is not activated, and is as a result, not bold.  The selection call works fine later on in the code - it is just during onCreate I am unable to get the desired effect.

Comment: I would recommend array of class instead of string and use that class to manipulate if you want if bold or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `choiceMode` before the `setItemChecked` can be used within your `ListView`

**sample:**

```
mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); 
mListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
```

EDIT:

Also call `mListView.notifyDataSetChange();` when you want to refresh the views from the listview after you checked the items.

EDIT:2

create a class

```
public class StringWrapper{ 
public String string; 
public boolean isBold = false; 
}
```

use that class as a wrappter to String

and change this

change this `title.setTypeface(null, title.isActivated() ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);` 
to

```
title.setTypeface(null, titles.get(position).isBold ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);
```

and change this: `mListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);`
to

```
titles.get(mCurrentSelectedPosition).isBold = true
mListView.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks I would recommend array of class instead of string and use that class to manipulate if you want if bold or not

Comment: I just tried wrapping the String with similar results.  See my edit at the bottom, it might be a big clue as to whats wrong

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks have you tried notifying it as I said above after you set

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks then class is what you need. and arrayList of class to the adapter.

Comment: I tried wrapping a String in a class with no success - how complicated does the class need to be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58851/discussion-between-rod-algonquin-and-mr-skid-marks).